# How to turn on magento error messages?

Tags: magento

I have installed Magento Community edition and tried creating my first simple hello world module. After a few hours I finally got it working.

My issues were I had used incorrect casing in some of the XML tags.

While trying to get it to work I tried to load the page a not found message was displayed, but no error.

I have switched errors on in the admin control panel `System > Configuration > Developer > Log Settings` and wrote a line which I know should have thrown an error but I just got a blank screen

1. How do I get errors to display in Magento?
2. Is it considered an error when I use incorrect casing in an xml file or is that an issue where I would not receive an error message? And if that is the case how would I quickly find the file that is causing the issue (obviously not a problem at the moment, but I can imagine as the module become functional it will be hard to find a single casing issue that is causing the problem)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

For enable error reporting

In Index page change the following:

`error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);`

to

`error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Set `$_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'] = true`

and uncomment this line

`#ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

In Errors folder rename `local.xml.sample` to `local.xml`.

hope this help.

Comment: That has helped start the error messages thanks.Is it possible to set something that will help me locate the source of the problem when I use incorrect casing in an xml file? e.g. using frontName the required page is returned, using frontname returns a page not found message, this simple thing had me pulling my hair out!

Comment: If you're running on Linux, you have xmllint to help ferret out layout xml file mistakes and malformation.

Comment: @tony09uk, please accept answer if it satisfies You.

Comment: The first change **decreases** error reporting. Setting dev mode should be done outside of Magento, e.g. using `SetEnv` in your `.htaccess` file.

Answer (score 18):

to complete the pankaj post,
this work for me
index.php

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'] = true;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are the steps that you should do in order to set Magento to display errors on the browser:

1. System > Cache Management > Disable All
2. System > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Log Settings > Enabled => Yes
3. System > Configuration > Web > Search Engine Optimization > Use Wbe Server Rewrites => Yes
4. System > Index Management > Reindex All
5. Open .htaccess and set: `SetEnv MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE "true"` at the end of the file
6. Open .htaccess and set: `php_value display_errors On` somewhere within
7. Rename or copy /errors/local.xml.sample to /errors/local.xml

Answer (score 1):

Modifying this code in magneto directory index.php:

```
Search for error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
```

Replace with

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'] = true;
```

OR
Uncomment it by removing the # sign from

```
#ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Refereed Link:
http://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-display-error-messages.html