# I need to store contact form data into database i did some piece of code but getting error in IndexController.php

Tags: php, mysql, magento

ERROR:

```
  Fatal error: Call to a member function setGuestName() on a non-object in IndexController.php
  {main}( ) - index.php
  Mage::run( ) - index.php(line:87)
  Mage_Core_Model_App->run( ) - Mage.php(line:684)
  Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch( ) - App.php(line:354)
  Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match( ) - Front.php(line:172)
  Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch( ) - Standard.php(line:250)
  Test_Contacts_IndexController->postAction( ) - Action.php(line:418)
```

My code:

```
  $model = Mage::getModel('contacts/contacts');
  $model->setGuestName( trim($post['name']) );
  $model->setGuestEmail(trim($post['email']));
  $model->setGuestTelephone(trim($post['telephone']));
  $model->setGuestComments(trim($post['comment']));
  $model->setGuestAttachment(trim($post['attachment']));
  $model->save( );
```

Comment: Check `setGuestName` is in contacts/contacts Model and access specifier should not be `private`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how your framework works, but shouldn't it be 
`$_POST['']` instead of `$POST['']`?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible the permissions are incorrectly set on contacts/contacts? Are you sure contacts/contacts is the right location?

Answer (score 0):

Please confirm your model object loading correctly by using following code:

```
$model = Mage::getModel('contacts/contacts');
echo get_class($model);  
die;
```

This will print you model class name If it is loading correctly. Otherwise you need to check config xml.

If you want to save contact form data in database. Here it is teh nice extension: 
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ultimate-contact-us-page-1.html

Hope this help !!

Comment: I put the above code it not display anything. My config.xml code                                                                                                 <models> <contacts>
<class>Test_Contacts_Model</class>
<resourceModel>Contacts_mysql4</resourceModel>  
</contacts>
<contacts_mysql4>
<class>Test_Contacts_Model_Mysql4</class>
<entities>
<contacts>
<table>contact_details</table>
</contacts>
</entities>                
</contacts_mysql4>
</models>

Comment: you resource model name `Contacts_mysql4` and tag name is not matching `<contacts_mysql4>`. Also Please make sure your model name will be `Test_Contacts_Model_Contacts`

Comment: My local directory is like this: Test->Contacts->Model->Mysql4(folder),Contacts.php. Inside of the Mysql4 folder->Contacts(folder),Contacts.php. Inside of the Contacts folder->Collection.php.. Is it correct??

Comment: Yes. Change `<resourceModel>Contacts_mysql4</resourceModel>` tag to `<resourceModel>contacts_mysql4</resourceModel>` in config.xml

Comment: ya i changed but no changes in output.

Comment: then You need to debug line by line. turn on magento error. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17143406/how-to-turn-on-magento-error-messages/17143618#17143618

Comment: Nw it displaying like Unable to submit your request. Please, try again later Once i click the submit button