# Magento admin bug

Tags: php, magento, admin

I've tried several things (listed below) but I still can't get it to work. The frontend of the magento shop works fine. The backend however has an problem, it just displays a header and nothing else

Things I have tried but where not successful:

- Replaced the core folder with a fresh core from a downloaden Magento
- Disabled cookies within core
- cleared cache / locks etc etc folder by hand
- Different browsers to check if it's session based

Only thing left to do now is reinstall Magento completely and just cipy my skin folders etc. But I'd rather not to that.

Comment: There are now error logs being created sadly, I've run this command to enable them: 

INSERT INTO core_config_data (scope, scope_id, path, value) VALUES ( 'default', '0', 'dev/log/active', '1');

and chmodded my folders but still nothing shows up

Comment: Enable the error reporting http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17143406/how-to-turn-on-magento-error-messages/17143618#17143618

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to  check  is there any problem in extension in (local/community) disable extension and check after clear cache

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Somehow during the transfer some data got lost