# After connecting Magento to database, Magento website returns blank

Tags: magento

We have been moving to another provider for our domain and wanted to update Magento from 1.8 to 1.9.1.
So this is what we have done:

- Export database from phpMyAdmin and importing it into phpMyAdmin via the BigDump.php file.
- We have downloaded Magento 1.9.1 files and put it into a directory on the FTP server.
- Then we got some files from our old website and put it into the new Magento files on the FTP
  Source: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/23931/magento-1-8-cant-upgrade-to-1-9

Now I went to install our Magento. Put in our database name, username, password and so on...
But when we clicked on the continue button, we got redirected to the following url:
http://mydomainname.com/index.php/install/wizard/installDb/

This page was blank, and so were the others...

Is there anything I did wrong? Any more information needed?

We have been struggling moving our website and upgrading it on the same time...

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

In Short, you need to follow the following Steps:
1. First Install Magento 1.9.1 With Database A 
 2. Login In admin panel clear Magento cache and disable.  
 3. Create Database B and import Old Site Database here. 
4.Connect your new Magento 1.9 Installation with Database B 
5.Reload the home page.

There may be some error occur. Otherwise it will be successful.

Hope this Help !!

Comment: @Pankjaj Pareek And ofcourse, I will mark it as answer

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work. I still get the blank page. Any other suggestions you have?

Comment: please enable error message. here is the instruction - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17143406/how-to-turn-on-magento-error-messages/17143618#17143618